# Change the CSS of the last div in a column

Tags: jquery

I have a table of 6 rows and 7 columns. Each cell is initially a gray circle. When I click on a circle I need to change the background color of the *last non-blue* circle from the same column starting from the bottom row to blue.

This code works only when the circles on the last row are grey. It would not change the color of the circle on the second to last row if the circle on the last row is blue. Any help or tips are welcome!

```js
$(".circle").click(function() {
  var colindex = $(this).closest('td').index() + 1;

  for (i = 6; i > 0; i--) {
    var cell = $('tr:nth-child(' + i + ') td:nth-child(' + colindex + ')');
    if (cell.find('div').css('background-color') === 'blue') {
      i--;
    } else {
      cell.find('div').css('background-color', 'blue');
      break;
    }
  }
})
```

```css
table {
  margin: auto;
  width: 50% !important;
}

.circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: #706e6e;
  border: 4px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve your goal you can get the index of the `td` which contains the clicked `.circle`. From there you can retrieve all `.circle` elements in the column. If you then use a class to set the style on the relevant circles, `.blue` in the example below, you can retrieve the last available circle and add the class to it. Something like this:

```js
$(".circle").click(function() {
  let $circle = $(this);
  let colIndex = $circle.closest('td').index();
  $circle.closest('table')
    .find('tr td:nth-child(' + (colIndex + 1) + ') .circle:not(.blue):last')
    .addClass('blue');
})
```

```css
table {
  margin: auto;
}

.circle {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #706e6e;
  border: 4px solid black;
}

.circle.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
    <td><div class="circle"></div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Note that I only made the circles smaller in this example so that they fit in to the snippet better.

Comment: Thank you so much for your precious help. Makes perfect sense. I am still trying to figure out what is wrong with my code. I am new to jquery.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `.css('background-color')` cannot be the same as the color name, but it must be the same value as the RGB. So the uquivalent to blue is `rgb(0, 0, 255)`. Also if it recognizes the last element as blue , it will not have to iterate i--, because at the next cycle it will iterate again minus 1, adding it to the previous one, iterate minus 2.

Your for loop code should be like this:

```
for (i=6;i>=0;i--){

    var cell = $('tr:nth-child('+i+') td:nth-child('+colindex+')');

    if(cell.find('div').css('background-color')!=='rgb(0, 0, 255)'){

        cell.find('div').css('background-color','blue');
        break;

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes of course I forgot to delete the i-- because I initially had used a while loop. Thanks for the tip about the rgb equivalent. Did not know that!